# Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in

Tags: magento2, module

facing this issue:

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first
>   statement or after any declare call in the script in
>   /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News.php
>   on line 3

Here's my code:

```
<?php

 namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

 use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Registry;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
 use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

 class News extends Action
{
 /**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
      protected $_coreRegistry;


      protected $_resultPageFactory;

     /**
     * News model factory
       *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
       */
     protected $_newsFactory;

 public function __construct(
Context $context,
Registry $coreRegistry,
PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
NewsFactory $newsFactory
  ) {
  parent::__construct($context);
      $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
   }


 protected function _isAllowed()
     {
return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
      }



public function execute()
 {
   /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
     $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

  return $resultPage;
}

}
```

Comment: Check your php file, there should be nothing before <?php tag, I have faced same and in that case I have a space before php opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

without comment, you are not allowed to use any white space after the opening of PHP tag in the .php file in the Block folder. So remove white space or add /**/ to fix this issue which you are getting during the compilation

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
just need to format code means before namespace space need to remove

```
<?php
namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

class News extends Action
{

  protected $_coreRegistry;


  protected $_resultPageFactory;

 /**
 * News model factory
   *
 * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
   */
 protected $_newsFactory;

  public function __construct(
 Context $context,
  Registry $coreRegistry,
PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
 NewsFactory $newsFactory
     ) {
  parent::__construct($context);
  $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
$this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
 $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
  }


 protected function _isAllowed()
 {
return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
  }



 public function execute()
  {
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
 $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

  return $resultPage;
  }

   }
```